# Displaying full-screen notifications in Android when receiving FCM notifications

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an Android application that receives Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) notifications. I want to display full-screen notifications whenever the app receives an FCM notification, regardless of whether the app is in the background or foreground.

I've tried implementing a solution where I create a full-screen intent and show a notification using NotificationCompat.Builder, but it doesn't work as expected. The notification is displayed as a regular notification, not full-screen.

Could someone provide a complete example or guide me on how to correctly implement full-screen notifications in Android when receiving FCM notifications?

Comment: You could display the notification in a notification channel which has importance set to `IMPORTANCE_HIGH`. Then it would pop-up over the top of whatever the user is doing.  Note that this should only be done if the notification may require an immediate action, e.g. it tells them that a message initiated by a human has just arrived.  EDIT: According to the documentation, such notifications "May use full screen intents".